# How could we prove the sentences?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B$ sets.

How could we prove the following sentences?

- $A \subset B \rightarrow \cup A \subset \cup B$
- if furthermore $\varnothing \neq A$ and $A \subset B$, then $\cap B \subset \cap A$.

$$x \in \cup A \leftrightarrow  \exists b \, (b \in A \wedge x \in b)$$

$$x \in \cap A \leftrightarrow \forall b \in A, x \in b$$

Comment: From $\exists b\left(b\in A\wedge x\in b\right)$ it follows directly that
$\exists b\left(b\in B\wedge x\in b\right)$, i.e. $x\in\cup B$. This because $A\subset B$. Also the intersection case can be solved that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object is a member of a member of $A$, then it is a member of a member of $B$; therefore the first statement is true.

Specifically, if $x\in a\in A$, then, since $A\subset B$, we have $a\in B$, and so $x\in a\in B$; hence $x\in \cup B$.

Now suppose $x\in\cap B$.  Then for ALL $b\in B$, $x\in b$.  Since every member of $A$ is a member of $B$, the fact that something holds for every member of $B$ means it holds for every member of $A$.  Thus for ALL $b\in A$, $x\in b$.  That means $x\in\cap A$.  This works even if $A=\varnothing$ if one allows proper classes; in other words, the intersection of all members of the empty set is the universe.

Comment: Michael Hardy, so can we prove the first sentence like that?
$$$$
Let $x \in \bigcup A$. So, $\exists b \in A$, such that $x \in b$.
$$$$
Since $A \subset B$, we have that $b \in B$.
$$$$
Therefore, $x \in b \in B$ and so: $x \in \bigcup B$.
$$$$
Therefore: $$\bigcup A \subset \bigcup B $$

Comment: Yes. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Michael Hardy Nice, thank you very much!!!!